# display mysql results in table with subrow?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I think i might have gotten in over my head. What I have is two tables in mysql with a common field. Id like to display one record in a table with a row or list of all those records common to it by the common field.

In detail, i have a table of yarn with images and a table of patterns with images. Id like to display the pattern and its info in one row and then underneath it all of the yarn images that match the common field of weight in a sub row of sorts.

I am also selecting color and category of pattern through checkbox groups.

here are my checkbox groups

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Black">Black
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue">Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Brown">Brown
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green">Green
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Grey">Grey
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Orange">Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Pink">Pink
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Purple">Purple
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red">Red
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Teal">Teal
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="White">White
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Yellow">Yellow



<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Home Decor">Home Decor
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Children">Children
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Tops Women">Tops Women
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Accessories">Accessories
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Lace">Lace
<input type="checkbox" name="pattcat[]" value="Tops Men">Tops Men
```

here is my query and display table for results so far. I have all of the image names saved in the mysql table and linked to a path.

```
extract($_GET);

$query = "(SELECT tblPatterns.PatternName, tblPatterns.Needlesize, tblPatterns.FinishedSize, tblPatterns.YardageNeeded, tblPatterns.PatternImage, tblYarn.YarnImage FROM tblYarn, tblPatterns WHERE tblYarn.WeightCategory=tblPatterns.WeightCategory && Color IN ('" . implode("','",$color) . "') && Category IN ('" . implode("','",$pattcat) . "') ORDER BY `tblPatterns`.`PatternName` ASC)" ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
 }
echo "<td><img src=./images/$col_value width='150' height='150' border='3' ></td>";


echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

I'm thinking I might have to change the foreach ($line as $col_value) part. Is there a way to build a table and choose exactly what data goes where and whether it repeats? As in the image from the yarn repeated under the row with its corresponding pattern data?

Comment: And please, for the safety of your code, use something like PDO to make your code less injectable.  As it stands, it's begging for someone to do sql injection.

Comment: Wow... `extract($_GET);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$last_pattern = null;
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $col_count = count($line) - 1; // Subtract 1 because image isn't in a column
  if ($line['PatternName'] !== $last_pattern) {
    if ($last_pattern !== null) {
      echo "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    echo "<tr>\n  ";
    foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value) {
      switch ($col_name) {
      case 'YarnImage':
        break;
      case 'PatternImage':
        echo "<td><image src='images/$col_value' /></td>";
        break;
      default:
        echo "<td>$col_value</td>";
      }
    }
    $last_pattern = $line['PatternName'];
    echo "</tr>\n  <tr><td colspan='$col_count'>\n";
  }
  $yarn_image = $line['YarnImage'];
  echo "    <img src='images/$yarn_image' width='150' height='150' border='3'/>\n";
}
if ($last_image !== null) {
  echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: this still gives me a repeat of each pattern for each yarn image, i'm getting a list of mysqlresults and then a broken image underneath each one.

Comment: I don't really know what your data is. I assumed the `PatternImage` column is the name of the file in the `images` directory with the image you want to display. Maybe it should be using `tblYarn.YarnImage`. Are these filenames?

Comment: Are you saying that it shouldn't display a table row for each row returned by the query, because there are multiple images with the same values in the table row? So you want to merge all of them into one table row, with all the images below it? Which columns should be used to determine if they're the same, or do you have to compare all of them (except the image)?

Comment: yes both the tblPatterns.PatternImage and tblYarn.YarnImage are filenames. They are both stored in the /images dir for now. I would like to display the PatternImage in line with all other info from tblPatterns and then underneath tied to it by the common field WeightCategory I would like to display the YarnImage in a row.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. Whenever `PatternName` changes it prints a row containing the values and the `PatternImage`. Below that, it displays a row containing all the `YarnImage`s for that pattern name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN tblPatterns with tblYarn :)

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Also, the image TD is outside the foreach, so it will not loop with $col_value preceding it.

Comment: im a student so forgive me, but havent i already joined tblPatterns with tblYarn by selecting FROM tblPatterns, tblYarn? Right now I get no image of the pattern and a repeat record of pattern info for each image of yarn.